# new in R, i need some help sum in rows

Tags: r

i am new in R and i have the following problem:
I am working with a data.frame of morethan 3000 obs an 6 variables.

```
     [PLOT] [SPP]   [tree] [BA] [...] []
[1]     2     A       1       3
[2]     2     B       2       2
[3]     2     C       3       5
[4]     3     A       1       4
[5]     3     C       2       7
[6]     4     B       1       4
[7]     4     D       2       5
```

[PLOT]and [SPP] are factor, [BA] is numeric
I am using:

```
data1 <- ddply(data,c('PLOT','SPP'),summarise,BAtotal = sum(BA,na.rm=TRUE))
```

But i want another col with this: %BA per SP and per plot. How it is possible to do? is possible to do with sapply??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mutate` instead of `summarise`

```
library(plyr)
ddply(data,c('PLOT','SPP'),mutate,BAtotal = sum(BA,na.rm=TRUE))
```

NOTE This will work only if the 'data' is `data.frame` and not a `matrix`.  It seems that the OP's data is `matrix`.  In that case, convert to `data.frame`

```
data <- as.data.frame(data)
```

before running the `ddply` code.

In addition to the above code, we can also use the `dplyr` methods (should be faster)

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    group_by(PLOT, SPP) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(BAtotal = sum(BA, na.rm=TRUE))
```

---

Or `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, BAtotal := sum(BA, na.rm=TRUE), by = .(PLOT, SPP)]
```